IntelliJ - fix alt+shift+space
I'm using intellij and I have this issue:
every time I hit Control+shift+space to autocomplete a windows's contextual menu pops out at the top-left corner (and also the autocomplete is triggered).
Is there a way to cahenge either the intellij or windows's menu
shortcut?
The picture of the menu opened is attached:


Generally the keymaps can be changed under File - Settings - Keymap

The Windows O.S. has owned the Ctrl+Space shortcut for decades. Check the Keymap settings in IntelliJ to remap it there.

I was using eclipse mapping, it was an error there, now I put it on alt+numpad0 (twice)

Windows uses Alt+Shift+Space as a system shortcut. I found no way to remap it; even PowerToys cannot effectively do that.
You may want to select another keymap for IntelliJ IDEA. Here is the list with the comparison: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Keymaps_Comparison_Windows.html

Thank you, I found out my idea was set to "eclipse" shortcuts, I remapped it to alt+numpad0 (twice). Thanks for helping.
